# Create a list of all values for each key in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I like to create a list of zip codes for each county, and assign this to a dictionary that has keys as name of counties. For example if I have zip codes and county columns from a csv file such as

| Zip code | County |
| --- | --- |
| 92606 | Orange |
| 92607 | Orange |
| 90026 | Los Angeles |
| 90027 | Los Angeles |
| 90028 | Los Angeles |

I like to have a dictionary such as

Orange  : [92606, 92607]

Los Angeles : [90026, 90027, 90028]

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to pandas, will be careful next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `groupby` and `.to_dict`

```
In [6]: df.groupby('County')['Zip code'].agg(list).to_dict()
Out[6]: {'Los Angeles': [90026, 90027, 90028], 'Orange': [92606, 92607]}
```

Comment: worked, thanks a lot. Very new to pandas, so very helpful, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would use a csv dictreader

```
import csv

file_name = "zip_codes.csv" #name of the csv file

with open(file_name, "r") as file: # opens the file (in read mode so nothing gets overwritten)
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    city_zip_dict = {} # make an empty dict to store the values
    for row in reader: #go through every row in the file
        county = row["County"]
        zip = row["Zip code"]
        if county not in city_zip_dict:
            city_zip_dict[county] = [zip] # Create a new list of zip codes for the county if there isn't one already
        else:
            city_zip_dict[county].append(zip) # if the county is already in the dictionary just add the new zip code to the list
```